# Function defined in coursework has unmapped domain?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Hi I was doing my Discrete Math coursework when I realise the function defined in the question has unmapped domain.

Note the definition of Zn*:

[image]

and in part c):

[image]

So basically you have f([3]) = [6] = [0], which maps to none of the codomain. How should I approach this?

Also, is the function injective? ( if both f( [ 7 ] ) = f( [ 1 ] ) = [ 2 ] ==> [ 7 ] =/= [ 1 ])??

Edit: I should add the domain and codomain do not seem to include [0].

Comment: Besides the big one you and the answer point out, there is another small imprecision in part c: At the first and third occurrence of "$f([x])$", it should really just say "$f$".

Comment: For your second-to-last line, note that $[1]$ and $[7]$ are different names for _the same_ equivalence class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that the definition fails to define a function $\mathbb Z^*_6\to\mathbb Z^*_6$.

Arguably that is a bug in the exercise. In that situation the best thing you can do is probably to *point out* the problem, *and* also explain that if we take the definition to define a function $\mathbb Z_6\to\mathbb Z_6$ instead, then it (is/is not) injective, and (is/is not) surjective.

---

Note that it is more common to take $\mathbb Z_n^\times$ to mean the group of all residue classes $[a]$ modulo $n$ **where $a$ and $n$ are coprime**. In that case, however, $\mathbb Z_6^\times$ would be $\{[1],[5]\}$ and the definition in the exercise *still* wouldn't define a function $\mathbb Z_6^\times \to \mathbb Z_6^\times$.

Answer (score -2):

Okay, f([0])= [2][0]= (2)(0)= 0= [0], f([1])= [2][1]= 2= [2], f([3])= (2)(3)= 6= [0], f[4]= [2][4]=  8= [2], and f[5]= [2][5]= 10= [4].  The "codomain" is {[0], [2], [4]}.  I don't know what you mean by "f([3])= f([6])= [0] maps to none of the codomain".  You just **said** that it maps to [0]!  What is true is that there is no "x" in the domain that maps to [1] (or to [3] or [5]).  This function is not surjective or "onto" the range space {[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]}.

Comment: did u read the definition carefully? Zn* does not include [0]